# How to solve issue of to insert duplicate data in database while users double click html button?

Tags: php, html, mysql

when you double click button in HTML and PHP data will be duplicated in database,
How to prevent that issue in my codes or phpmyadmin? because many users like to double click while saving the data

```
<form action="disabled.php" method="post">

   <button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
   <button type="button" id="myButton2" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
   <button type="button" id="myButton3" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
</form>

<script>
function myButtonClicked(obj) {
        obj.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
</script>
```

Please anyone can help me

Comment: a simple way is to use javascript to disable the button after it's clicked the first time

Comment: Additionally, issue clear instructions to the user on the page, and/or improve training (if this is a corporate application) to explain how to use it.

Comment: Another way would be to generate a unique one-time token for the form, and include it in a hidden field. If the server finds it is processing two requests containing the same token, it should reject the second one.

Comment: So there are quite a few ways, if you take some time to think creatively. There are probably other things I haven't thought of yet, too.

Comment: I tried to use the above codes but it does not send the page when you click button

Comment: If you want a button to submit a form, you must use `<button type="submit"` (not `<button type="button"`). This is explained in the documentation of `<button` already. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button . P.S. why have you got 3 different but identical buttons in your example? I couldn't work out the purpose of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable the button on click with javascript.